# How to reset activity background to theme default

Tags: java, android

I want to make a button to restore an activity background color to default when it's clicked. How do I do it ?

Edit: to be more clear restore to default mean change the background to what was given by the current theme when the activity was first created

Comment: What do you mean by restore and default?

Comment: By default I mean when it's first created with no color at all just the default background given to the activity by the theme. And by restore I think I need to be a bit more clear, I should have said that there will be 2 buttons in the activity one to change the background to a different color and the other to revert the background change to default